# Pause video on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, slide

I am creating a slider with images that when someone clicks one slide, opens a modal window with another slider with videos.

At the moment, when you click one of the images, it opens a video that auto plays. The problem is that if you click to see the next slide, the video keeps playing.

So I would like to pause the video when the slide moves...

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhLy4cng/51/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop video playing when using slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799115/how-to-stop-video-playing-when-using-slider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to @lonut who pointed me in the right direction:

```
var iframe = $('.vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('.carousel-control').bind('click', function() {
    player.api('pause');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pause the video using `pause()` method when going to next slide using:

```
$('.center').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  player.pause();
});
```

I declared the `player` variable globally outside the click event to be able to use `pause()` on it.

Please see the working updated **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hhLy4cng/52/)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid the fiddle is not working....

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? You can see that when you go to the next slide the video stops playing. It has a delay of a few seconds but that may be because of the slick plugin you use. Maybe using `beforeChange` would make it stop instantly when going to next slide.

Comment: I've checked the fiddle, but it seems that the pause is not working. If you open the first video and then you switch the slide, it will keep playing...

Comment: @patie, it works for the slick slide change. Now, actually I see that you don't use slick on the lightbox. How do you create the lightbox carousel?

Comment: Ok. Where do you initialize it? I don't see it anywhere being initialized...in the docs looks something like `$('#default-demo').slickLightbox({`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145439/discussion-between-patie-and-ionut).